# Wrong 1st Argument type "Found Activity, Required FragmentActivity" Google Login Error in Android

Tags: android, google-signin

I am trying to get the google+ login working on android. But I got error in this code :-

```
    // [START build_client]
    // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
    // options specified by gso.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
    // [END build_client]
```

It's showing this message :-

> Wrong 1st Argument type "Found SignInActivity, Required FragmentActivity"

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you write this code in Fragment?

Comment: pls post your class what you extend exactly so we understand what you make mistake

Comment: are you trying to compile googlesamples with SignInActivity here :
https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
You Will extending Activity instead  extend FragmentActivity.
Hope it helps. Thanks